# bitmap onDraw() not updating

Tags: android, draw

I'm trying to show a blue square on the view, then afterwards show a red square instead.

Problem is that its not drawing anything when it should draw a blue square, but when it should draw a red square, it not draws a blue one.

What am I missing here?

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if(runCount == 1)
    {
        // Color blue and save bitmap
        blueCanvas = new Canvas();
        blueBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0 , 200, 300, bgPaintBlue);
    }
    if(runCount == 2){
        // Color red
        redCanvas = new Canvas();
        redBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0 , 200, 300, bgPaintRed);
    }
    runCount++;
    invalidate();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to call **invalidate();** from onDraw method. Also didn't understand what exactly you trying to do, please elaborate more

Comment: I'm just trying to look into how the mechanism work after reading some theory about canvases, bitmaps and such. But I cant make sense of just this small example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to draw Bitmap on canvas, you need to attach the Bitmap to canvas and then draw as fast as you want.

```
    private Bitmap canvasBitMap = null;
    private Canvas bitmapCanvas = null;
      @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);


    int paddingLeft = getPaddingLeft();
    int paddingTop = getPaddingTop();
    int paddingRight = getPaddingRight();
    int paddingBottom = getPaddingBottom();

    int contentWidth = getWidth() - paddingLeft - paddingRight;
    int contentHeight = getHeight() - paddingTop - paddingBottom;

    mgraphWidth     = contentWidth;
    mgraphHeight    = contentHeight;

    if(canvasBitMap == null)
    canvasBitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mgraphWidth, mgraphHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    if(bitmapCanvas == null)
        bitmapCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitMap);

    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitMap,0,0,mgraphcolor);

    drawGraph(bitmapCanvas);
}
```

You can use this complete GitHub code to understand the graph/UI plotting using CustomView.

Fork this repository and use it as boilerplate.

https://github.com/Teju068/Android_Tutotrial

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the docs:

> **public void invalidate ()**
>
> Invalidate the whole view. If the view is visible, onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called at some point in the future.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()

As previously mentioned, you are calling invalidate inside the onDraw method itself, so it is creating an infinite loop. Meanwhile you are updating runCount in there as well, so it is continually incrementing that variable.

Although I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do, I would suggest to remove at least the statement

```
invalidate();
```

from inside the onDraw method and rethink your design. You can call invalidate from elsewhere in your program as long as you have reference to this view, but make sure the call is on the UI (main) thread.

Comment: In the end the solution should create a continuously line. Im just trying to understand how its updating the bitmap